# cannot find apache conf.d file in mac

Tags: apache, mamp

I am using MAMP on MAC OSX.

I am trying to create a virtual host using the code. It is in a file named LaravelTest.conf. However I will need to place this file in apache's conf.d directory (I believe).

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/l4/project/public"
ServerName LaravelTest
 <Directory "/path/to/laravel/project/public">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where do I find the conf.d directory ? It is not present in /etc/apache2

Answer (score 14):

Since you are using [mamp](/questions/tagged/mamp), you could find the `Apache` configuration file at

```
/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf
```

To be able to include your `vhost` file, you should add the following on the config

```
Include /path/of/LaravelTest.conf
```

Or you can just add an additional `VirtualHost` on your apache config file.